# Quicksort giving StackOverFlow error

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to write quicksort algorithm. I followed an online tutorial that has pretty much done the same thing, yet I'm getting a StackOverFlow error.

```
public void mysort(int[] g) {
    quickSort(g, 0, g.length - 1);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g));
}

public void quickSort(int[] nums, int low, int high) {
    int i = low;
    int j = high;

    int pivot = nums[(low + (high - low)) / 2];

    while (i <= j) {

        while (nums[i] < nums[pivot]) {
            i++;
        }

        while (nums[j] > nums[pivot]) {
            j--;
        }

        while (i <= j) {
            int temp = nums[i];
            nums[i] = nums[j];
            nums[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));

    if (low < j) {
        quickSort(nums, low, j);
    }

    if (i < high) {
        quickSort(nums, i, high);
    }
}
```

The array I've passed as an argument is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1].

In the quicksort method, the println statement outputs this after the first loop, [1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5].

What's going on here?

Comment: you can use a debugger to follow the steps of the program and to see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calculating the pivot wrong, it's not:

```
int pivot = nums[(low + (high - low)) / 2];
```

It is:

```
int pivot = nums[low +  ((high - low) / 2)];
```

`Division` in maths has a higher priority than `sum` and `sub`

In other words, you can write it as:

```
int pivot = nums[low +  (high - low) / 2];
```

Another problem you will find, is in your whiles, you are not asking for the pivot, you are asking for the number in the position of pivot `nums[pivot]`, it should be:

```
  while (array[i] < pivot) {
    i++;
  }

  while (array[j] > pivot) {
    j--;
  }
```

Finally, is not the exchange `while i<=j`it is:

```
  if (i <= j) {
    int temp = nums[i];
    nums[i] = nums[j];
    nums[j] = temp;
    i++;
    j--;
  }
```